# Visual Studio Conversion Wizard not showing backup option

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

While converting our solution from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010, I am not getting the screen where we select the backup option.

It is directly showing the final screen with `Conversion type: In-place with no backup`.

[image]

**Has any one faced this behavior when using the conversion wizard?**

Comment: Maybe it's **really** confident that it'll do no harm :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I had some issues with VSS last time I converted. It messed up with some web references and even deleted them from VSS. When I undo checked-out the entire project, still it was unable to get that reference. Thats the reason I need to take the backup.